# ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '...' for column '...' at row 1 when tring to change a column to a different datat type

Tags: mysql

My code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
ID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
firstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
lastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
login varchar(25) NOT NULL,
password text NOT NULL,
empType varchar(25) NOT NULL,
email varchar(90) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ;  

                                                                
INSERT INTO employee (firstName, lastName, login, password, empType, email ) values 
('Yvonne', 'Prince', 'yprince', "Parrots12!@", 'General Manager', 'yprince@ucfhotel.com'),
('Dante', 'Rennie', 'drennie', "Birbs12!@", 'Front Office Manager', 'drennie@ucfhotel.com'),
('Alysha', 'Waters', 'awaters', "Doggo12!@", 'Concierge', 'awaters@ucfhotel.com'),
('Avaya', 'Clarke', 'aclarke', "MurderMittens12!@", 'Concierge', 'aclarke@ucfhotel.com'),
('Haniya', 'Kaiser', 'hkaiser', "BlazingCruise12!@", 'Guest Service Agent', 'hkaiser@ucfhotel.com'),
('Nathalie', 'Newman', 'nnewman', "CruisingBlaze12!@", 'Guest Service Agent', 'nnewman@ucfhotel.com'),
('Dante', 'Guthrie', 'dguthrie', "Smokey12!@", 'Guest Service Agent', 'dguthrie@ucfhotel.com'),
('Beverley', 'Roberts', 'broberts', "Ocho8*", 'Guest Service Agent', 'broberts@ucfhotel.com'),
('Paris', 'Solis', 'psolis', "Samster12!@", 'Van Driver', 'psolis@ucfhotel.com'),
('Umaiza', 'Heath', 'uheath', "NattyPants12!@", 'Van Driver', 'uheath@ucfhotel.com'),
('Jonathan', 'Kumar', 'jkumar', "Keystonia12!@", 'Security', 'jkumar@ucfhotel.com'),
('Angus', 'Neville', 'aneville', "StormyCat12!@", 'Security', 'aneville@ucfhotel.com'),
('Uzair', 'Sparrow', 'usparrow', "OrangeMuffin12!@", 'Sales Director', 'usparrow@ucfhotel.com'),
('Amari', 'Currie', 'acurrie', "TessaDog12!@", 'Sales Manager', 'acurrie@ucfhotel.com'),
('Imaani', 'Wallace', 'iwallace', "IvyBug12!@", 'Catering Assistant', 'iwallace@ucfhotel.com'),
('Efe', 'House', 'ehouse', "AussieBird12!@", 'Executive Housekeeper', 'ehouse@ucfhotel.com'),
('Atticus', 'Atkinson', 'aatkinson', "Eclectus12!@", 'Houseperson', 'aatkinson@ucfhotel.com'),
('Michelle', 'Ramirez', 'mramirez', "Horse12!@", 'Houseperson', 'mramirez@ucfhotel.com'),
('Remy', 'Hassan', 'rhassan', "Equines12!@", 'Houseperson', 'rhassan@ucfhotel.com'),
('Jordana', 'Beck', 'jbeck', "AllAnimals12!@", 'Houseperson', 'jbeck@ucfhotel.com');`
```

then put emptype from table `employee` to the new table `employeeType`

```
CREATE TABLE employeeType(
ID int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
type varchar(90) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);

INSERT INTO employeeType (`type`) 
SELECT DISTINCT empType 
From employee;
```

Then I used this command

```
ALTER TABLE employee MODIFY COLUMN empType int(7) NOT NULL;
```

When I run the alter command, I get:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'General Manager' for column 'empType' at row 1

Comment: The value in `empType` in the 1st row is `'General Manager'` - what integer value do you want to obtain instead?

Comment: @Akina The integer value is going to be the ID(which is a int) from a table called employeeType, then ADD FOREIGN KEY (empType) REFERENCES employeeType (ID);

Answer (score 0):

You must:

1. Create a table which will store employee types;
2. Fill it with the values;
3. Add column in `employee` which will store the relational value and create foreign key relation;
4. Fill this column;
5. Drop initial column.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3956a7d021bd1fb367c78e6563e453d6